# Android, How to initialize Audio Recorder?

Tags: android, audio-recording, audio

I have created AudioMeter class and I have written following codes in its contractor:

```
public AudioMeter(){
        channel_config = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO;//And also Mono
        format = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
        sampleRate = AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM); //8000
        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channel_config, format);

        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleRate, channel_config, format, bufferSize);

        audioBuffer = new short[bufferSize];

        Log.i("AudioMeter", "Created successfully.");
    }
```

But when I run the emulator it says 
`01-29 03:47:07.418: E/AudioRecord(432): Unsupported configuration: sampleRate 44100, format 1, channelCount 2"`
I have added "`Audio Recording Support`" and "`Audio Playback Support`" into emulator.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been looking over this code for a while now!

Answer (score 4):

Emulator does not support CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO & sampleRate = (11025, 16000, 22050, and 44100), If u want to run this successfully so used CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO & SampleRate =8000(It only support 8000 sample per sec).